# Criar PDF a partir de um arquivo HTML GRANDE com DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Estou tentando converter um arquivo html de 40mb em PDF utilizando o DOMPDF.
Mesmo com timeout de 3600 segundos, ele não gera o arquivo, nem se eu colocar para como tarefa cron 1x ao dia ou executar em linha de comando.

meu script

```
<?php
    require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
?>
```

onde a variável `$html` é todo conteúdo do meu arquivo de 40 mega.

Gostaria de saber se alguém possui alguma classe de conversão mais eficiente, que trabalhe bem com arquivos grandes ou se o próprio DOMpdf tem este suporte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tive o mesmo problema. Não consegui encontrar solução com o DOMPDF. Com o Snappy não acontece o problema com o tamanho do arquivo, ele é muito rápido!

A biblioteca pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy).

Instalando via composer:

```
$ composer require knplabs/knp-snappy
```

É necessário os aplicativos Wkhtmltopdf e Wkhtmltoimage, disponíveis para Windows Linux e OS X disponíveis [aqui](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

Incluindo e usando a biblioteca no seu projeto:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

//adicione o caminho para o seu wkhtmltopdf como no exemplo abaixo
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');

//configure a pasta temporária para salvar o arquivo
$snappy->generateFromHtml($html, '/tmp/arquivo.pdf');

//force o download do arquivo
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
readfile('/tmp/file.pdf);
```

[Neste link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_K4SZ8a895JUEJna2dCLUg1YkE) disponibilizei a pasta com os arquivos caso não consiga baixar. Extraia o arquivo e coloque a pasta `vendor` e a pasta `wkhtmltox` na raiz do seu projeto.

O caminho do wkhtmltopdf será `'__DIR__./wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf'`

Comment: desculpe a ignorância mas eu tenho um servidor com cpanel que hospeda o site do meu cliente e preciso gerar o pdf, mas não estou conseguindo utilizar.
Por acaso você poderia me passar o zip dos arquivos para uso ?
Eu baixei as bibliotecas do git e os downloads do site mas nem o arquivo autoload.php existe

Comment: Editei a resposta e coloquei os arquivos.

Comment: muito bom , parabéns e obrigado pela ajuda